# Laravel Homestead Serve code not creating and connecting to folder(s)

Tags: php, nginx, laravel-4, vagrant

I have tried running the following code, and even though it runs and sets the nginx blocks ok, its not linking to the folder in question with in the host machine.

```
  serve projects.dev /home/vagrant/Code/projects.dev
```

When i then list the folders within the Code folder on the guest machine, i only get the folders that were created via the automated Yaml config file on init set up.

It seems not be creating the folder and/or linking to it at all with between the guest and host machines

Running it on a iMac OS Mavericks.
Vagrant 1.6.2
VirtualBox 4.3.12

Answer (score 0):

That is strange.  What I have is I have a folder mapped on the "folders" section from my host machine that inside contains all the sub-folders for all my projects in progress.  So my nginx sites just basically link to the sub-folders inside this directory.  If you have something like that it "should" show you the folders from your host inside that Code directory in your VM.  Maybe post your YAML file to check it out?

Comment: its not the yaml set up, all my settings on here work fine i was just testing the idea of the serve function that i would not need to go into ssh etc and create it via there.  The serve call works and created the sites file etc but the physical folder does not display up on the guest machine so the sites-enabled root has nothing to link to if you know what i mean, thanks for the reply

Answer (score 0):

My problem was the new Homestead file, use small c for spelling directory "code".

I was upgrading my homestead, so the old code folder was using capital c, spelled "Code".

I just change my Homeastead.yaml file from calling "code" to "Code".